# Problema al ejecutar una clase Controlador

Tags: java, mvc, java-swing

Lo que quiero hacer es crear un **Controlador** para cada **Vista**, pero al crear un segundo controlador este no funciona, no abre la ventana o **JIntenarFrame** que corresponde.

Tengo este código en el controlador de la ventana principal, funciona bien, pues acciona a las órdenes de la **Vista**:

```
package ControladorProyecto;

import InterfazProyecto.Proyecto_Admin;
import InterfazProyecto.Proyecto_Clientes;
import static java.awt.Frame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class Proyecto_ControladorAdmin implements ActionListener{

    private Proyecto_Clientes cliente= null;
    private Proyecto_Admin factureAdmin= null;

    private enum Ventana{
        getJMenuClientes,
    }

    public Proyecto_ControladorAdmin(Proyecto_Admin factureAdmin){
        this.factureAdmin= factureAdmin;
    }

    public void abrirFacture(){
        //Inicialización del Frame factureAdmin
        this.factureAdmin.setTitle("FACTURE");
        this.factureAdmin.setExtendedState(MAXIMIZED_BOTH);
        this.factureAdmin.setVisible(true);

        //Definición de los eventos de los Componentes
        this.factureAdmin.getJMenuClientes().addActionListener(this);
        this.factureAdmin.getJMenuClientes().setActionCommand("getJMenuClientes");
        //this.cc= new ControladorCliente();
    }

    //Centrar los JInternalFrame en el Desktop
    public JInternalFrame centralizarInternalFrame(JInternalFrame InternalFrame) {
        int x = (this.factureAdmin.getDesktop().getWidth() / 2) - InternalFrame.getWidth() / 2;
        int y = (this.factureAdmin.getDesktop().getHeight() / 2) - InternalFrame.getHeight() / 2;
        if (InternalFrame.isShowing()) {
            InternalFrame.setLocation(x, y);
        } else {
            this.factureAdmin.getDesktop().add(InternalFrame);
            InternalFrame.setLocation(x, y);
            InternalFrame.setVisible(true);
            InternalFrame.moveToFront();
        }
        return InternalFrame;
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
        switch (Ventana.valueOf(ae.getActionCommand())) {

            case getJMenuClientes:
                if (!(this.cliente instanceof Proyecto_Clientes)) {
                    this.cliente = new Proyecto_Clientes();
                    this.cliente.setTitle("CLIENTES");
                    this.centralizarInternalFrame(this.cliente);
                } else if (this.cliente instanceof Proyecto_Clientes) {
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "La ventana ya está abierta");
                }
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

El **verdadero problema** está en este código que corresponde al segundo **Controlador**, no acciona a las órdenes de la **Vista** abriendo el **JInternalFrame** que debe:

```
package ControladorProyecto;

import InterfazProyecto.Proyecto_Admin;
import InterfazProyecto.Proyecto_Clientes;
import InterfazProyecto.Proyecto_NuevoCliente;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.JInternalFrame;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class Proyecto_ControladorCliente implements ActionListener{

    private Proyecto_Admin factureAdmin= null;
    private Proyecto_Clientes clientes= null;
    private Proyecto_NuevoCliente nuevoCliente= null;


    private enum Componentes{
        txtBuscarCliente,
        tablaClientes,
        getBtnRegistrarCliente
    }

    public Proyecto_ControladorCliente(Proyecto_Clientes clientes){
        this.clientes= clientes;
    }

    public void abrirCliente(){
        this.clientes.getBtnRegistrarCliente().addActionListener(this);
        this.clientes.getBtnRegistrarCliente().setActionCommand("getBtnRegistrarCliente");
    }

    public JInternalFrame centralizarInternalFrame(JInternalFrame InternalFrame) {
        int x= (this.factureAdmin.getDesktop().getWidth()/2)- InternalFrame.getWidth()/2;
        int y= (this.factureAdmin.getDesktop().getHeight()/2)- InternalFrame.getHeight()/2;
        if(InternalFrame.isShowing()){
            InternalFrame.setLocation(x, y);
        }else{
            this.factureAdmin.getDesktop().add(InternalFrame);
            InternalFrame.setLocation(x, y);
            InternalFrame.setVisible(true);
            InternalFrame.toFront();
        }       
        return InternalFrame;
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
        switch (Componentes.valueOf(ae.getActionCommand())) {

            case getBtnRegistrarCliente:
                if (!(this.nuevoCliente instanceof Proyecto_NuevoCliente)) {
                    this.nuevoCliente = new Proyecto_NuevoCliente();
                    this.nuevoCliente.setTitle("NUEVO CLIENTE");
                    this.centralizarInternalFrame(this.nuevoCliente);
                } else if (this.nuevoCliente instanceof Proyecto_NuevoCliente) {
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "La ventana ya está abierta");
                }
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

No sé por qué el segundo *Controlador* no me funciona.

Los demás códigos corresponden a los demás **JInternalFrame** para que puedan reproducir el problema.

El siguiente código corresponde a la clase que inicializa el proyecto.

```
package Proyecto;

import ControladorProyecto.Proyecto_ControladorAdmin;
import ControladorProyecto.Proyecto_ControladorCliente;
import InterfazProyecto.Proyecto_Clientes;
import InterfazProyecto.Proyecto_Admin;

public class IncializarProyecto {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Proyecto_Admin factAdmin = new Proyecto_Admin();
        Proyecto_Clientes cl = new Proyecto_Clientes();

        new Proyecto_ControladorAdmin(factAdmin).abrirFacture();
        new Proyecto_ControladorCliente(cl).abrirCliente();
    }
}
```

Este es de la *Ventana principal* del proyecto o **ProyectoAdmin**:

```
package InterfazProyecto;

public class Proyecto_Admin extends javax.swing.JFrame {

    public Proyecto_Admin() {
        initComponents();
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">
    private void initComponents() {

        desktop = new javax.swing.JDesktopPane();
        jPanel1 = new javax.swing.JPanel();
        menus = new javax.swing.JMenuBar();
        jMenuProduccion = new javax.swing.JMenu();
        jSubMenuClientes = new javax.swing.JMenuItem();

        setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        desktop.setBackground(new java.awt.Color(0, 102, 102));

        javax.swing.GroupLayout desktopLayout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(desktop);
        desktop.setLayout(desktopLayout);
        desktopLayout.setHorizontalGroup(
            desktopLayout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGap(0, 400, Short.MAX_VALUE)
        );
        desktopLayout.setVerticalGroup(
            desktopLayout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGap(0, 250, Short.MAX_VALUE)
        );

        javax.swing.GroupLayout jPanel1Layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(jPanel1);
        jPanel1.setLayout(jPanel1Layout);
        jPanel1Layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGap(0, 400, Short.MAX_VALUE)
        );
        jPanel1Layout.setVerticalGroup(
            jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGap(0, 23, Short.MAX_VALUE)
        );

        jMenuProduccion.setText("Producción");

        jSubMenuClientes.setText("Clientes");
        jMenuProduccion.add(jSubMenuClientes);

        menus.add(jMenuProduccion);

        setJMenuBar(menus);

        javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
        getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
        layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addComponent(desktop)
            .addComponent(jPanel1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
        );
        layout.setVerticalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addComponent(desktop)
                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                .addComponent(jPanel1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
        );

        pack();
    }// </editor-fold>

    public static void main(String args[]) {

        try {
            for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
                if ("Windows".equals(info.getName())) {
                    javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                    break;
                }
            }
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Proyecto_Admin.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Proyecto_Admin.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Proyecto_Admin.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Proyecto_Admin.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }

        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                new Proyecto_Admin().setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    // Variables declaration - do not modify
    private javax.swing.JDesktopPane desktop;
    private javax.swing.JMenu jMenuProduccion;
    private javax.swing.JPanel jPanel1;
    private javax.swing.JMenuItem jSubMenuClientes;
    private javax.swing.JMenuBar menus;
    // End of variables declaration

    public javax.swing.JDesktopPane getDesktop(){
        return desktop;
    }

    public javax.swing.JMenuItem getJMenuClientes(){
        return jSubMenuClientes;
    }
}
```

A continuación, este código corresponde al *JInternalFrame* **ProyectoClientes:**

```
package InterfazProyecto;

public class Proyecto_Clientes extends javax.swing.JInternalFrame {

    public Proyecto_Clientes() {
        initComponents();
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">
    private void initComponents() {

        jScrollPane1 = new javax.swing.JScrollPane();
        tablaClientes = new javax.swing.JTable();
        txtBuscarCliente = new javax.swing.JTextField();
        btnRegistrarCliente = new javax.swing.JButton();

        setClosable(true);
        setIconifiable(true);
        setMaximizable(true);
        setResizable(true);
        setToolTipText("");

        tablaClientes.setModel(new javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel(
            new Object [][] {
                {},
                {},
                {},
                {}
            },
            new String [] {

            }
        ));
        jScrollPane1.setViewportView(tablaClientes);

        btnRegistrarCliente.setText("Registrar Cliente");

        javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
        getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
        layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addContainerGap()
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                    .addComponent(jScrollPane1)
                    .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addComponent(txtBuscarCliente, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 353, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                        .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED, 65, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                        .addComponent(btnRegistrarCliente)))
                .addContainerGap())
        );
        layout.setVerticalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addContainerGap()
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                    .addComponent(txtBuscarCliente, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                    .addComponent(btnRegistrarCliente))
                .addGap(18, 18, 18)
                .addComponent(jScrollPane1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 304, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                .addContainerGap())
        );

        pack();
    }// </editor-fold>

    // Variables declaration - do not modify
    private javax.swing.JButton btnRegistrarCliente;
    private javax.swing.JScrollPane jScrollPane1;
    private javax.swing.JTable tablaClientes;
    private javax.swing.JTextField txtBuscarCliente;
    // End of variables declaration

    public javax.swing.JTable getTablaClientes(){
        return tablaClientes;
    }

    public javax.swing.JTextField getTxtBuscarClientes(){
        return txtBuscarCliente;
    }

    public javax.swing.JButton getBtnRegistrarCliente(){
        return btnRegistrarCliente;
    }
}
```

Y por último el código del *JInternalFrame* que no funciona cuando se acciona el botón del *JInternalFrame* descrito arriba **(ProyectoClientes)** y que corresponde al segundo controlador, ***es este JInternalFrame el que no se muestra en el JDesktopPane de la ventana Proyecto_Admin***.

```
package InterfazProyecto;

public class Proyecto_NuevoCliente extends javax.swing.JInternalFrame {

    public Proyecto_NuevoCliente() {
        initComponents();
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">
    private void initComponents() {

        lblFotoCliente = new javax.swing.JLabel();

        lblFotoCliente.setIcon(new javax.swing.ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/InterfazProyecto/imagenes/1475738020_kuser.png"))); // NOI18N
        lblFotoCliente.setBorder(javax.swing.BorderFactory.createEtchedBorder());

        javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
        getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
        layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGap(6, 6, 6)
                .addComponent(lblFotoCliente)
                .addContainerGap(572, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );
        layout.setVerticalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGap(6, 6, 6)
                .addComponent(lblFotoCliente, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 154, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addContainerGap(217, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );
        pack();
    }// </editor-fold>

    // Variables declaration - do not modify
    private javax.swing.JLabel lblFotoCliente;
    // End of variables declaration
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Utilza `InternalFrame.moveToFront()` en lugar de `InternalFrame.toFront()` en el segundo ejemplo.

Comment: Hola @Kevin. ¡Bienvenido a [es.so] y gracias por contribuir! ¿Podrías explicar brevemente por qué el cambio solucionaría el problema?

Comment: Hice lo que dijiste hombre, pero no funciona. Además sinceramente, no entiendo el cambio, no es que no se vuelve a mostrar es que no se muestra.

Comment: Bienvenido al sitio Kevin, es importante revises [answer], saludos.

Answer (score 0):

¿En qué momento inicializas o inyectas el valor correspondiente a la variable `factureAdmin` del segundo controlador?  En el método  `centralizarInternalFrame` haces uso de la variable `factureAdmin`.

**Ejemplo:**

```
int x= (this.factureAdmin.getDesktop().getWidth()/2) InternalFrame.getWidth()/2;
int y= (this.factureAdmin.getDesktop().getHeight()/2)- InternalFrame.getHeight()/2;
```

La variable `factureAdmin` es igual a `null` en esa parte, lo más probable es que ese sea el origen de tu problema, además no entiendo bien tu ejemplo. ¿Acaso no deberías usar `clientes` para obtener la información de la altura o anchura?

Si pudieras explicar más a fondo en que consiste cada clase, edito la respuesta y veo si el origen de la problemática cambia. Pero por lo pronto esas son las observaciones que veo en tu código.

Comment: En ese caso, voy a poner todo el código necesario para que puedas reproducir el problema